# Get folder basename no matter the operating system path separator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cannot seem to find a function that works for both windows and unix path separators. Is there a native way to get the files basename no matter what the separator is?

`basename` doesn't seem to work when using windows separators. So I am converting them to Unix using regex but I don't like that approach:

```
With regex    -> Documents 
Without regex -> C:\path\to\Documents
```

Can I replace the regex with something more native to node's `path`/`path-browserify`?

```
import * as path from 'path';

function basename(directory: string) {
  path.basename(directory.replace(/\\/g, '/'));
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, was thinking Python.

Comment: This seems to work `path.basename(new URL(i).pathname)`, however, I'm not 100% sure I like it...